# Should I set IsReusable to True in my HttpHandlers?

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler

I've never fully understood [this property of the IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.isreusable(VS.71).aspx).  It is a property that you have to set when you implement the interface.  I've assumed that setting it to true would be better for performance, but I am not sure what the negative side effects might be.  Should I return true or false?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Significance of bool IsReusable in http handler interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539302/significance-of-bool-isreusable-in-http-handler-interface)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is used to indicate if a single instance of the IHttpHandler will be used to process multiple concurrent requests. So if you set it to `true` it will improve performance but you must make sure that your code is thread safe because the `ProcessRequest` method might be invoked from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: The handler is fairly simple, and it does nto need to maintain state.  It should be thread safe.  So I think I can set it to true!  Thank you.

Comment: When you have private member variables in the handler and make use of the context is this threadsafe?

Comment: Can you please explain **because the ProcessRequest method might be invoked from multiple threads at the same time.** ?

Answer (score 3):

If your `IHttpHandler` implementation contains state (perhaps setup in the constructor and later used in `ProcessRequest`) then it can sometimes be useful to set `IsReusable` to false.

Answer (score 3):

IsReusable keeps the handler in memory and able to handle multiple requests. When set to false, it has to create a new instance of the handler for each incoming request.

I had some issues with this property myself:

[Streaming Databased Images Using HttpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507572/streaming-databased-images-using-httphandler)